# Setting up UIViewController before pushing/presenting it

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

In my app, I use a UINavigationController to switch between many different UIViewControllers. The only problem is that with one of my views, upon it loading, I have to do lots of customization (both data access and graphics, both of which must be done in code). When the view controller is pushed, the animation is extremely choppy, because the phone is forced to both animate the transition and set up the view at the same time.

Setting up the view after it is loaded is not an option, so is it possible to set it up (there is a method called setupViewDidLoad that has all of the necessary code in it) during allocation *before* it is pushed/presented?

Edit:

Let me modify my question slightly. I have found that if I present the view controller using [self presentModalViewController:animated:] instead of pushing it with the navigation controller, there is no choppiness. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to do this.  Set up any code you need in viewWillAppear in your views .m file.  If you have to access data remotely you may want to think about creating a data storage class of its own to handle and store that so it can do it whenever - even if the view isn't loaded or hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: You know, I actually have no answer for your edit honestly.  That's strange.  The navigation controller would be presenting a new view to the stack of views that your navigation controller controls.  A modal view is just simply presenting an upper layer view on top of everything you currently have - so maybe since it isn't controlled in a stack it can load slightly faster?  Just an educated guess at this point.

Comment: Yeah; it seemed like an odd problem because when I switched from displaying all of the views modally (never noticed any animation lag then) to using the navigation controller, I was surprised at how choppy the UINavigationController was. It is an interesting problem; for now I am just going to present that view controller modally instead of with the navigation controller, since it will be the very top one anyway.